# Check if directory exists on remote machine

Tags: java, filesystems

How to check if directory exists on remote machine?

I want to create directory on remote machine. For that I need to check if the directory is present on remote machine. Is there any way in java to check this?

I want something like this

```
File f = new File("http:/sac/svn/MockRepo/Mockrepo/branches/eQubeQa/Definitions/sac_cat/")
if(!f.exists()){
    //create directory
}
```

I know there is exist method in File class.
It works with local file system.
But for remote directory it always returns false.

Please give me the sample code.

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 2) How do you create a directory on the remote machine? 3) *"Please give me the sample code."*  That is not how SO works.

Comment: On which OS your java program runs ? What is the target OS ?

Comment: My code runs on Windows OS

Comment: @user2745675 what is the OS of the remote machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have proper permission You could ssh into that machine (assuming you have permission) using JSch library and then execute set of commands to determine if directory exist

Comment: I have all the required permissions. can u please give me sample code?

Comment: You would need ssh access to remote machine

Answer (score 1):

If you can have access to a FTP server on the remote machine, you may try to connect through FTP and detect if your directory exists.

Here is a sample code:

```
package net.codejava.ftp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

/**
 * This program demonstrates how to determine existence of a specific
 * file/directory on a remote FTP server.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class FTPCheckFileExists {
    private FTPClient ftpClient;
    private int returnCode;

    /**
     * Determines whether a directory exists or not
     * @param dirPath
     * @return true if exists, false otherwise
     * @throws IOException thrown if any I/O error occurred.
     */
    boolean checkDirectoryExists(String dirPath) throws IOException {
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dirPath);
        returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (returnCode == 550) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to a remote FTP server
     */
    void connect(String hostname, int port, String username, String password)
            throws SocketException, IOException {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(hostname, port);
        returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(returnCode)) {
            throw new IOException("Could not connect");
        }
        boolean loggedIn = ftpClient.login(username, password);
        if (!loggedIn) {
            throw new IOException("Could not login");
        }
        System.out.println("Connected and logged in.");
    }

    /**
     * Logs out and disconnects from the server
     */
    void logout() throws IOException {
        if (ftpClient != null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Logged out");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs this program
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "www.yourserver.com";
        int port = 21;
        String username = "your_user";
        String password = "your_password";
        String dirPath = "Photo";

        FTPCheckFileExists ftpApp = new FTPCheckFileExists();

        try {
            ftpApp.connect(hostname, port, username, password);

            boolean exist = ftpApp.checkDirectoryExists(dirPath);
            System.out.println("Is directory " + dirPath + " exists? " + exist);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                ftpApp.logout();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [Determine if a directory exists on ftp server](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/determine-if-a-directory-or-file-exists-on-ftp-server)

Comment: I am getting errors at following line
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.FTPClient;

I guess I need to add some jar for this. Can you tell me which jar need to be added in classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You may not able to `access` folders in remote machine directly due to `permission` issues.

Comment: I have all the permissions